# VSCode python can't import from parent folder

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode on Windows as my IDE and my project structure looks like this:

```
`project_folder`

|---- `folder1`

|     |---- `folder2`

|     |     |---- `foo.py`

|     |---- `bar.py`

      .  
      .
      .
```

In `foo.py` I have this import statement:
`from folder1.bar import SomeClass`

I can directly run that statement using PyCharm, but when I run it with VSCode I get the following error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder1'`

I tried modifying `.vscode/settings.json` and `.vscode/launch.json` following some tutorials but it didn't work.

I don't want to modify the system path using `sys.path.append` as it doesn't sound practical to do for every single file in the repo.

Comment: Add source code

Comment: @kj-crypto There is everything you need to answer the question

Comment: How do you run`foo.py`?

Comment: From the VSCode IDE.

Comment: I mean from which directory you run this code? In pycharm there is checkbox which adds source path to PYTHONPATH and that can cause the problem. If you run `foo.py` from inside of `folder2` than `from folder1.bar` as a relative import doesn't see `folder1` under the `folder2`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)

Comment: @3ddavies no, as I want to avoid using relative imports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the problem with avoiding `sys.path.append` or relative imports. Just set the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` and set the value to the path to your project root.

Comment: If you're using linux, create a .bashrc file which contains `export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/your/repo` and before running your scripts, execute `source .bashrc`